# Download xml file from the website and stored in desired location (java / selinium with chrome browser)

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Download xml file from the website and store in desired location (java / selinium with chrome browser)

below is the html code

```
<!-- Start of Code which handles XML Download-->
<a href="javascript:downloadXML()">
<img src="/img/tabs/downloadxml.gif" alt="Download" name="imag34" width="40" height="20" border="0">
</a>
<!-- End of Code which handles XML Download-->
```

first, click the image and the file should automatically stored in my desired location

below is my chrome configuraion

```
File file = new File("resources/chromedriver.exe");
        String downloadFilepath = "mydownload path";
        Map<String, Object> preferences = new Hashtable<>();
        String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", absolutePath);

        preferences.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
        preferences.put("download.prompt_for_download", "false");
        preferences.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", preferences);

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Execution

```
while clicking the image the xml file downloaded in my desired location with 0kb size
```

Question:
why the file not downlaoded completely? any mistake in my code?

Answer (score 0):

MIME need to be defined.  Try adding something similar to below, which handles for Excel files

```
 profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 
                    "text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/octet-stream");
 profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile",
                    "text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/octet-stream");
```

For more info on MIME types, please refer https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/mime-types-supported

MIME type for xml is **application/xml**